# On the spacetime significance of Feynman diagrams (and Witten diagrams)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, feynman-diagrams, quantum-interpretations, ads-cft

This post is just a thought about **[Feynman  diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram)** and their interpretation. When I draw a FD, my intention is to provide a direct way to calculate  terms in a series expansion. Now, from what I understand, the FDs are embedded in a sort of "spacetime", with a time and space directions well defined. If we set the physical process, for instance, in a Minkowski spacetime, the lines and the angles between lines become fundamental as information for the process (I'm thinking here on the $45°$ for the speed of light). However, I think that this is not the right interpretation for these diagrams, but I'm not so sure. In fact, I have recently found the **[Witten diagrams](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Witten+diagram)**, which seem the equivalent of FDs in the case of AdS spacetime (or CFT). So, I'd like to understand the role of the spacetime in both FDs and WDs: is it just a starting hypothesis that we have to keep in mind or maybe is its contribution in that pictures more relevant?

Comment: Are the space/time axes on Feynman diagrams not simply there for clarity? The internal/external lines on Feynman diagrams are not intended to represent worldlines of particles like you might draw on a Minkowski diagram.

Comment: Yes, this is my first interpretation. So the Witten diagrams are actually the same things but in different context?

Comment: Feynman diagrams don't really have anything to do with spacetime. They're simply a diagrammatic representation of a perturbative expansion; an enumerative device or a mnemonic aid, if you will. I don't know enough about Witten diagrams to make an educated comment about them, but the case appears similar at surface level.

Comment: Perfect! I think exactly the same things! And, now, I imagine that, in some sense, Witten diagrams helps in the same way as FDs, but with also the "hint" regarding the different spacetime, in which they work. It would be interesting to provide a clarification also for WDs!